# Nexus 6 with developer preview no mobile data

Tags: nexus-6, 7.0-nougat, developer-preview

The mobile data 4G/LTE is not working on my nexus 6 and I think it is because of the beta preview of android nougat latest version announced today. When I was with marshmallow it was working fine but now even when I asked people in the store to set up the APN it is not working. 2G/3G also don't work but I can receive and give calls to other numbers. Anyone having the same issue?

**Edit:** It turned out the problem was from the mobile operator. I should probably have checked that first.

Comment: If you have solved your own problem, then please post your solution as an answer and accept it. This will help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I have the developer preview on my Nexus 6 as well as on my Nexus 6P. But I don't have any issues like you have.
 But I read a post on the internet with a similar issue. Did you flashed the preview via the normal system  update method ? 
I suppose that is the case with you. What fixes this problem is to manually download the system images from Google Developer site and flash it using ADB and Fastboot.

It is an easy process to do. It has a `batch file` called `flash all.bat` (I dont remember accurately ) or with a similar name (might be `runme.bat`). Once you run that script just wait. Your phone will restart several times and under 2 mins the process will complete.

[Download the system images for Android N](https://developer.android.com/preview/download.html)

 Scroll and choose your device and the download will be initiated. Good Luck

Comment: I did it with a normal system update. Thanks for the suggestion. I will try it and see if it works!

Comment: @Nikola  Then this method will work perfectly for you ! Do tell me the results you get !